# Creating a new Pandas DataFrame from an Existing One

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, grouping

I have a pandas dataframe which has a month based data as follows:

```
  df 

   id Month  val
   g1   Jan    1
   g1   Feb    5
   g1   Mar   61
```

What I want is the following:

I want to convert the dataframe to a week structure with the month column(replaced or not) by all the weeks which can happen in that month, So the output should look like:( thus 4 weeks for each month)

```
   new_df 

     id  week  val
     g1     1    1
     g1     2    1
     g1     3    1
     g1     4    1
     g1     5    5
     g1     6    5
     g1     7    5
     g1     8    5
     g1     9   61
     g1    10   61
     g1    11   61
     g1    12   61
```

I have tried using the following function and apply it to the pandas dataframe, but that's not working:

```
SAMPLE CODE

      def myfun(mon):
        if mon == 'Jan':
           wk = list(range(1,5))
        elif mon == 'Feb':
           wk = list(range(5,9))
        else:
           wk = list(range(9,13))
        return wk

   df['week'] = df.apply(lambda row: myfun(row['Month']), axis=1)
   del df['Month']
```

The output I am getting is as follows which is not what I want:

```
       id    val         week
       g1    1     [1, 2, 3, 4]
       g1    5     [5, 6, 7, 8]
       g1    61  [9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Also is there a neat way to achieve this?

Help will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`Dataframe.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with `range(4)`. On the output we use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with the method forwardfill `ffill` to replace the `NaN`.

After that we convert `Month` to datetime format with [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), so we can sort on month.

Finally we create the column `Week` bij getting the index and adding 1 and drop the `Month` column:

```
# extend index with 4 weeks for each month
df_new = pd.concat([
    d.reset_index(drop=True).reindex(range(4))
    for n, d in df.groupby('Month')
], ignore_index=True).fillna(method='ffill')

# Make a datetetime format from month columns
df_new["Month"] = pd.to_datetime(df_new.Month, format='%b', errors='coerce').dt.month

# Now we can sort it by month
df_new.sort_values('Month', inplace=True)

# Create a Week columns
df_new['Week'] = df_new.reset_index(drop=True).index + 1

# Drop month column since we dont need it anymore
df_new.drop('Month', axis=1, inplace=True)
df_new.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

---

Which yields:

```
print(df_new)
    id   val  Week
0   g1   1.0     1
1   g1   1.0     2
2   g1   1.0     3
3   g1   1.0     4
4   g1   5.0     5
5   g1   5.0     6
6   g1   5.0     7
7   g1   5.0     8
8   g1  61.0     9
9   g1  61.0    10
10  g1  61.0    11
11  g1  61.0    12
```

---

Comment: Well this is not going to work. I want Jan to be 1-4, Feb 5-8, Mar to be 9-12 and so on..

Comment: Yes I see, makes sense. Edited my answer with correct output @Stan

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
month={'Jan':1,'Feb':2,'March':3,'April':4,'May':5,'June':6,'July':7,'August':8,'Sept':9,'Oct':10,'Nov':11,'Dec':12}
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'week', 'val']) # create a new dataframe
for index,row in df.iterrows(): # for each row in df
    month_num=(month[row[1]]-1)*4+1 # to get the starting week order from the dictionary "month"
    for i in range(4): # iterate four times 
        # append (add) the row with the week value to the new data frame
        new_df = new_df.append({'id':row[0],'week':month_num,'val':row[2]}, ignore_index=True)
        month_num+=1 # increment the week order
print(new_df)
```

Comment: The issue is that the solution is not OK, as I need a month specific WW too. So if it is Jan it should be 1-4, Feb 5-8 so on and the data can start from April also so in that based on the month the count should be taken.

Comment: I updated the code to reflect the month issue, hope that helps.@Stan

Comment: Perfect makes sense. Thanks